# Can't resolve "Error Code: 1114. The table is full"

Tags: mysql

I've stumbled upon a quite irritating issue. After upgrading my computer (win 10) to a much better CPU, hard drive storage capacity and 128GB of RAM I suddenly get the "Error Code: 1114. The table is full" when previously the code was working fine with only 8GB of RAM. The original table is innodb and has about 10m rows. I've read through various previous suggestions and I'm still stuck...

- Table size is 1.3GB
- @@tmdir: C:\Windows\SERVIC~1\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
- Harddrive (C:) has 660GB of free space
- Innodb_buffer_pool size is now 42 GB vs 8 GB before
- There is ample of hard drive space left
- InnoDB_data_file_path has been set to: ibdata1:12M:autoextend
- tmp_table_size set to 134mb vs. 36mb before
- max_heap_table_size set to 16.8mb (same as for my old computer)
- I've also tried to drop/add back the indexes, optimize and partition the table without luck.

After about 25s I continously get the "Error Code: 1114. The table is full" when on my previous computor I could run the query well over 180s until it was completed.

Here's the primary view-query and underlying the cascade of views / tables used to run the query.

```
    -- Primary Query 
    CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `financialmodeling`.`view_fm_output_stockdata_other` AS 
    select 
    `financialmodeling`.`t3`.`UInstrumentID` AS `InstrumentID`,
    `t4`.`Year` AS `Year`,
    `t4`.`Week_` AS `Week`,
    `t4`.`Month` AS `month`,
    `t4`.`EndOfWeekDate` AS `date`,
    `t0`.`date` AS `ReportedDate`,
    avg(`t0`.`close`) AS `Close`,
    avg(`t0`.`volume`) AS `Volume`,
    min(`t0`.`LastUpdate`) AS `Lastupdate` 
    from (`stockdatabase2_0`.`tbl_admin_standarddates` `t4` 
      left join (`financialmodeling`.`tbl_fm_raw_stockdata_other` `t0` 
         left join `financialmodeling`.`view_fm_instrumentid` `t3`
         on((`financialmodeling`.`t3`.`symbol` = `t0`.`symbol`))) 
      on((`t4`.`Date_` = `t0`.`date`))) 
    where ((`t0`.`date` > '2015-01-01') or (`t0`.`date` < '1950-01-01')) 
    group by `InstrumentID`,`t4`.`EndOfWeekDate`

    -- Secondary Queries
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_admin_standarddates` (
       `Date_` date NOT NULL,
       `EndOfWeekDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `EndofMonthDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `StartofQDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `EndOfQDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `Week_` int NOT NULL,
       `Month` int NOT NULL,
       `Quarter` int NOT NULL,
       `Year` int NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`Date_`),
       KEY `Week__index` (`Week_`),
       KEY `Month_index` (`Month`),
       KEY `Quarter_index` (`Quarter`),
       KEY `Year_index` (`Year`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_fm_raw_stockdata_other` (
       `symbol` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       `date` date NOT NULL,
       `close` decimal(20,3) DEFAULT NULL,
       `volume` decimal(20,3) DEFAULT NULL,
       `LastUpdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10582560 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
     /*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (`id`)
     PARTITIONS 10 */

    CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `financialmodeling`.`view_fm_instrumentid` AS 
    select 
    `financialmodeling`.`t0`.`symbol` AS `symbol`,
    concat('FM-',`financialmodeling`.`t0`.`symbol`) AS `UInstrumentID`,
    `financialmodeling`.`t0`.`LastUpdate` AS `lastUpdate` 
    from `financialmodeling`.`view_fm_symbols_grosslist` `t0`


    CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `financialmodeling`.`view_fm_symbols_grosslist` AS 
    select 
    `t0`.`symbol` AS `symbol`,
    `t0`.`name` AS `name`,
    `t0`.`exchange` AS `exchange`,
    `t0`.`type` AS `Type`,
    `t0`.`lastupdate` AS `LastUpdate` 
    from `financialmodeling`.`tbl_fm_raw_symbols` `t0` 
    union 
    select 
    `t1`.`symbol` AS `symbol`,
    `t1`.`name_` AS `name_`,
    `t1`.`exchange_` AS `exchange_`,
    `t1`.`type` AS `Type`,
    `t1`.`lastupdate` AS `LastUpdate` 
    from (`financialmodeling`.`tbl_fm_raw_symbols_other` `t1` 
    left join `financialmodeling`.`tbl_fm_raw_symbols` `t2` on((`t1`.`symbol` = `t2`.`symbol`))) 
    where (`t2`.`symbol` is null)

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_fm_raw_symbols` (
   `symbol` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `price` decimal(20,3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `exchange` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lastupdate` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`symbol`,`exchange`),
   KEY `symbol_Index` (`symbol`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_fm_raw_symbols_other` (
    `symbol` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `name_` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `currency` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `exchange_` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `exchangeshortname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastupdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`symbol`,`exchange_`),
    KEY `symbol_Index` (`symbol`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: `SELECT @@tmpdir;` -- is that directory in its own "filesystem"?  If so, how big?

Comment: `(t0.date > '2015-01-01' or t0.date < '1950-01-01')` looks quite strange.  Also it is slow.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables; I need to check some things.

Comment: Have you heard or considered changing your engine to RocksDB ?  I also encountered many problems with big tables in innoDB, since I changed to MariaDB and installed RocksDB : it's day vs night... https://mariadb.com/kb/en/myrocks/

Comment: @RickJames - I've updated the original post to cover your answers. The "where" statement is due to I use "1900-01-01" as identifyer for instruments with empty data. It shouldnt be leading to any issues since it has the same syntax when running it on my old computor.

Comment: @Jintor - no havnt tried that yet but will do. In any case it is frustrating if there is no apparent reason for InnoDB to stop working when running on an identical mashine except for better hardware. Would it perhaps be easer and reliable to use a paid service like Microsoft SQL instead?!

Comment: @user2693457 When I was facing issues with innoDB, I explored many other possibilities, but in all my tests MariaDB with RocksDB turned out to be the best choice because it automatically adapts... you can have machine with low ram or high ram, it will still work... I also noticed that innoDB handles poorly mysql crashes, it often brakes the whole table :( but with RocksDB, when mysql crashes (example out of physical ram), the table is intact and don't need repair...